# Calling Function from RootViewController

Tags: objective-c

How to call a `RootViewController` function from `FirstViewController`?
I'm using Xcode 4.6 with storyboard.

---

RootViewController.m:

```
-(void)openMenu
{
    ...
}
```

FirstViewController:

```
- (IBAction)btnMenu:(id)sender {
    RootViewController *root = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
    [root openMenu]; // No visible @interface for 'RootViewController' declares the selector 'openMenu'
}
```

Comment: Why are you wanting to call a method that appears to be UI related from a different controller?

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare the method in your header `RootViewController.h`. Example

```
- (void)openMenu;
```

Answer (score 1):

A common practice for something like this is to use delegation.  Your `FirstViewController` would have a delegate and then your `RootViewController` would set the delegate for the instance, and receive the information for the event.

**FirstViewController.h**

```
@protocol FirstViewDelegate;

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong) id<FirstViewDelegate> delegate;

@end

@protocol FirstViewDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)openMenu;

@end
```

**FirstViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)btnMenu:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate openMenu];
}
```

**MainViewController.h**

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface RootViewController : UIViewController
<
FirstViewDelegate
>
```

**MainViewController.m**

```
-(IBAction)showFirstViewButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    firstViewController.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:firstViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)openMenu {
   // this will be called when the btnMenu action is fired in the firstViewController
}
```